# Is AMQP suitable for building a video ad distribution system?

Tags: video, rabbitmq, distribution, amqp, ads

I'd do some work on video advertisement distribution. My application is that there exist many mobile terminals in different areas which would play video ads. Those terminals(ex. those installed in elevators) are conneted to a control server. When video advertisements in different types published on the server, they are distributed to related termanals through a designed strategy. My assumption is that we use the AMQP-based rabbitmq server to implement the distribution. Terminals subscribe different topics on the server, and the server push those video ads according to the topic.

But as far as I know rabbitmq is more used in message notification. 
Can the "message" be some kind of video type? Does AMQP fit for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the MQ as a message distribution system as you subscribe with links to a DB of videos.  The client would receive a message according to the topic and that message will tell it which video to download and play.  That way you have small payloads running through your broker but it can still distribute according to you specifications.

Comment: Do you mean to push not the video to the related terminal directly but a message to notice the terminal to download the video from the server itself?

Comment: Yeah, maybe it works. But What are the disadvantages of pushing the binary stream of the video, just like other common message types, to terminals directly? The message size is seemingly not limited in AMQP.

Comment: Theoretically there is no problem with sending large files, but the system is not optimized to do so.  I really do not know what kind of bottlenecks could occur doing this.  I would guess that converting the file to a byte stream and then back again will have a much bigger cost than sending a link and downloading, just my guess though